# How can I deserialize json object where in keys are present pointer?

Tags: java, json, gson

I need to deserialize this json

```
{"dal.device.status":1,"dal.device.UID":"ZigBee:Yale Doorlock:ah.app.3781220503199452-1","service.bundleid":77,"dal.device.driver":"ZigBee","service.id":159,"service.scope":"singleton"}
```

But I don't how to do since there are pointers in key (e.g. "dal.device.status") I'm using google gson.
I'm able to deserialize this object using C# and Newtonsoft library using ClassAttributes. Is there something similar for java?

Comment: The json structure is horrible, some string parse would work but i wouldn't prefer it. You can deserialize it with naming your variable names like: dal.device.status but it's just horrible.

Comment: In Java it's not possible put pointer in name variable @SercanOzdemir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question when seeing properties with dot in them in a json should be "god, oh god, why ? why all this hatred ?"

But if earth is at stake, you can simply deserialize this mess into an hashmap using gson and work from here.

Comment: It's third part library and is closed source so I'm not able to change nothing. But I've solved the problem using @JsonProperty